# Passing variables over to another file

Tags: c, unix, gcc, floating-point

The values change when being used in ellipsefunctions.c, which I don't understand. The values aren't static either, and change depending on A, B, C, while h and k are the same. Can soemeone tell me whats going on?

a.out was compiled using 'gcc ellipsemain.c ellipsefunctions.c'

Couldn't post the screenshot because I don't yet have enough rep, but here's a link to it

i.stack.imgur.com/Ag6Vg.png (if screenshots aren't your thing look below)

ellipsemain.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(6 > argc){
        printf("Too few arguments, please follow the format: <executable> <A> <B> <C> <h> <k>\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(6 < argc){
        printf("Too many arguments, the program will still attempt to run using the first 5 inputs\n");
    }

    float A = atof(argv[1]);
    float B = atof(argv[2]);
    float C = atof(argv[3]);
    int h = atoi(argv[4]);
    int k = atoi(argv[5]);

    printf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n%d\n\n\n", A, B, C, h, k);
    usingany(A, B, C, h, k);
    printf("\n\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n%d\n", A, B, C, h, k);
    return 0;
}
```

ellipsefunctions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usingany(float A, float B, float C, int h, int k);


void usingany(float A, float B, float C, int h, int k)
{
    printf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n%d\n", A, B, C, h, k);
    return;
}
```

console:

y:~/ENEE150/ENEE150HW1/Problem1: a.out 1 1 1 1 1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1
1

1.875000
0.000000
1.875000
0
1072693248

1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1
1

Comment: Please post your code code and output in your question instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: @mb595x Just did! Please check it out.

Comment: @nutclump - I notice you are about as new to this site as I am ( I've been 4 days so far ): When/If you confirm an answer has been significant to you on this or the other questions you ask, please consider [marking an answer as 'Accepted'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

<del>There are two problems here:</del>

<del>1: You are 1-indexing your `argv` variables.</del>

<del>All arrays in C are 0-indexed, you should be getting elements `[0] [1] [2] [3] and [4]`</del>

Correction, I had forgotten the program name is in argv[0], you were doing this right.   I will assume that the issue is simply the following:

2: In my tests, the problem of actually getting different values from `usingany` is that you have not defined it for `main` to know how to pass the data.

If I compile that program with the gcc -Wall flag, I get this output:

```
$ gcc m.c e.c -Wall
m.c: In function 'main':
m.c:14:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'usingany' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

In general, implicit function take no arguments, and return an int.

You need to take the definition you have at the top of ellipsefunctions, and move it into ellipsmain, or a shared header file.

```
void usingany(float A, float B, float C, int h, int k);
```

Comment: @nutclump - great! I totally blanked on #1, I was very wrong, but I said it so confidently I even had myself convinced. I used a strike through and edited that I was wrong.